# Show that $c$ is in interval $[e,3]$ for $c\cdot \ln{c} + c − 6 = 0$

Tags: calculus

Show that there is a unique number $c \in \mathbb{R}$ that fulfills the equation and that this number is in the interval $[e, 3]$.

$$ c\cdot \ln{c} + c − 6 = 0$$

At first I was thinking about using linear approximation, but then I would need an $a$ and $x$. So I'm quite confused as how to start solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note $c>0$.

Set $e^y:=c$, then

1)$ye^y +e^y -6=0$,

$e^y(1+y)-6=0$.

$f(y):=(1+y)e^y-6.$

$f(0)=-5;$

$f'(y)=e^y+(1+y)e^y \gt 0$ for $y \ge 0$.

Strictly increasing for $y \ge 0.$

$y=1$: $f(1)= 2e-6 <0$.

$y=\log 3$:

$ f(\log 3)=(1+\log 3)3-6>0$,

since $\log 3 >1$.

Recalling $c=e^y:$

$c \in [e,3]$.

2) Let $y \le 0$.

A) $-1 \le y \le 0.$

$f(y)=(1+y)e^y -6= (1-|y|)e^{-|y|}-6 \le -5.$

$f(0)=-5$; $f(-1)= -6.$

B) $y \lt -1.$

$f(y)= (1+y)e^y -6 \lt -6.$

Combining:

$f(y) \lt 0$ for $y \le 0.$

$f(y)$ is strictly increasing for $y \ge 0$.

Hence $f(y)$ has exactly one zero, $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That doesn't work, because your condition $y\ge 0$ is equivalent to $c\ge 1$. To cater for $c\in(0,1)$, you need to consider all $y\in \Bbb R$; and $f'(y)$ goes negative as $y$ goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: TonyK.Thanks.Mistake.

Comment: TonyK.Hopefully fixed.Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if i'm worng, but i only need to show that unique number c in interval $[e,3]$ makes equation = 0. So the simplest way to proof it would be using intermediate value theorem. $e*ln(e)+e-6=2*e-6<0$ and $3*ln(3)+3-6=3*ln(3)-3>0$ with means that function/equation is intersects x-axis at the value c with makes equation = 0.

Comment: Fork.Yes. IVT, as you applied it, gives one zero(means at least one zero). But there could be more! But if f is strictly increasing in this interval there is exactly one zero.Your thoughts ?

Comment: Function is strictly increasing in the interval since $f(e)<f(3)$, so there should be exactly one zero?

Comment: Fork. You need f'(y)>0, or you show directly that a <b , implies f(a) < f(b), for any!! points in the interval, not just the end points.ok?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x\ln(x)+x-6$.

$f$ is continuous on $[e,3].$

and
$$\forall x\in [e,3] \; \; f'(x)=\ln(x)+2>0$$
$f$ is strictly increasing on $[e,3]$.
$$f(e)=2e-6\approx -0.4$$
$$f(3)=3\ln(3)-3>0$$

by IVT, $$\exists \; \color{red}{!} \;c\in[e,3] \; : f(c)=0$$

Comment: But the function is not strictly increasing on the whole of $\Bbb R_{>0}$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes but we are in concern with the intervall $[e,3]$.

Comment: I suggest you read the OP's question more carefully!

Comment: @TonyK I did it. Now i invite you not to read my answer.

Comment: I don't understand that, I'm afraid. Did you read the bit that says "a unique number $c\in\Bbb R$"?

Comment: @TonyK Do know what $\exists !$ means. ! !.

Comment: I give up.${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x + x ln(x) - 6$

Since,

$f(e)=2e-6 <0$

and

$f(3)=3 ( ln(3) - 1) > 0 $

and because $f$ is continuous on $ [e,3]$ and differentiable on $(e,3)$, and also $f'(x) = ln(x) +2 > 0$ (strictly increasing), using the intermediate value theorem, there is such a $c$.

Note: The uniqueness comes from the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Your answer is repetitive, quoting the wrong theorem, and not addressing the uniqueness

Comment: @dionelJaime I was typing in my own solution independently and improving it incrementally. There are many people faster than me, here. I'm in no competition with anyone whatsoever, dude.

Comment: The function is not strictly increasing on $\Bbb R_{>0}$.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm just having a bad day. Sorry.